# Bug or syntax change on Debian's "curl" 7.36? Mess when trying to save sequential files with brackets/hash

Tags: debian, curl

(Perhaps specifically 7.36.0-1, which is shown as the most recent available on my package manager).

I think there was such a bug some time ago, **but perhaps it was back in curl 7.33**, I can't remember.

Basically if you wanted to download a sequence of files with something like:

```
curl www.url.com/[1-100]/fulltext.pdf -o fulltext#1.pdf
```

It would make some mess, I don't remember the results exactly, but it wouldn't work. Like overwriting the same file or interpreting "[1-100]" literally, as a folder or a file that isn't there (I think it was that what actually happened). The same download/syntax would work fine with curl 7.26, which is the one I downgraded to.

Does anyone knows if such functionality is working right with the most recent curl, on Debian? I'm wary of upgrading and then not being able to downgrade back if it no longer works, whenever I may use it. Also I guess I'd fill some sort of lousy bug report, if it's confirmed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you quote those arguments properly in your shell. [] and # both have special shell behaviors in some contexts.